# How to parse mysql with pyparsing

Tags: python, mysql, pyparsing

I'd like to parse the INSERT statements from MySql dumps, and `pyparsing` seems like a good candidate, but I'm having trouble understanding how to start with it.

The string format I have looks like this:

`` INSERT INTO `table` VALUES ('simple string value','isn\'t this a (very) complex value',7),('value','value',1); ``

where there can be multiple tuples of data, and `value` can include brackets and escaped quotes.

Also, this is all binary strings, as `value` can have a variety of encodings or just binary data ... but the quotes will still be escaped.

Can anyone offer any help? Or suggest alternative approaches?

Comment: Although it is written for another purpose, you may check https://github.com/stephenharris/py_obfuscate which is handling insert statements

Comment: There are a couple of SQL SELECT parsers included in pyparsing's examples directory (https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/master/examples/select_parser.py and https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/master/examples/simpleSQL.py).  They should give you a lead on how to start with some basic INSERT statement parsing.